# How can I search and condense repetitive rows in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I'm using R to process RNA sequencing data, to which I'm very new. I'm using data frames of reference material from BioMart which, when GO terms are included, are very badly arranged (as follows).

```
head(goZref)
      Gene.stable.ID Transcript.stable.ID  Protein.stable.ID
1 ENSDARG00000063344   ENSDART00000131829 ENSDARP00000123357
2 ENSDARG00000063344   ENSDART00000131829 ENSDARP00000123357
3 ENSDARG00000063344   ENSDART00000144883 ENSDARP00000114467
4 ENSDARG00000063344   ENSDART00000144883 ENSDARP00000114467
5 ENSDARG00000097685   ENSDART00000156963 ENSDARP00000128236
6 ENSDARG00000097685   ENSDART00000156963 ENSDARP00000128236
                                                            Gene.description         Gene.name WikiGene.name
1 family with sequence similarity 162 member A [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:336363]           fam162a       fam162a
2 family with sequence similarity 162 member A [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:336363]           fam162a       fam162a
3 family with sequence similarity 162 member A [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:336363]           fam162a       fam162a
4 family with sequence similarity 162 member A [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:336363]           fam162a       fam162a
5                      si:ch211-235i11.3 [Source:ZFIN;Acc:ZDB-GENE-131125-9] si:ch211-235i11.3  LOC101885363
6                      si:ch211-235i11.3 [Source:ZFIN;Acc:ZDB-GENE-131125-9] si:ch211-235i11.3  LOC101885363
                                                       GO.term.name
1                                                          membrane
2                                    integral component of membrane
3                                                          membrane
4                                    integral component of membrane
5                                              nucleic acid binding
6 RNA polymerase II regulatory region sequence-specific DNA binding
```

I want to annotate a data frame of genes of interest (the gene names are in a character vector called `genes` here), but I'm struggling to automate it given all the repetition and row duplication in the references. I've tried using `match` but because it only finds the first instance of something I miss out on other rows. I would like to, for instance, search for "fam162a" and get something like "membrane, integral component of membrane", and then automate this for a list of 100 gene names. `subset` is useful in giving me multiple rows with the same gene name identifier, and I've tried to pass it to `ddply` but I don't really know what I'm doing and got stuck here:

```
test<- ddply(.data = goZref, .variables = genes, for (x in genes) {
+ paste(unique(subset(goZref, WikiGene.name==x, select= Go.term.name)), sep = ",")})
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:12: unexpected symbol
1: si:dkey-224k5.13
               ^
```

**Edit:** My desired output would be something like a matrix of my input 100 gene names and the corresponding info from all relevant rows in the Go.description column, for example if fam162a and LOC101885363 were the genes in the list the output would be:

```
1 fam162a       membrane,integral component of membrane
2 LOC101885363  nucleic acid binding,RNA polymerase II regulatory region...
```

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Please show your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(Gene.name = c("fam162a", "fam162a", "fam162a", "fam162a", "LOC101885363", "LOC101885363"),
                 Gene.info = c("membrane","integral component of membrane", "membrane", "integral component of membrane",
                               "nucleic acid binding", "RNA polymerase II regulatory region sequence-specific DNA binding"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

SOLUTION:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Gene.name) %>% 
  mutate(Gene.info.complete = paste0(unique(Gene.info), collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Gene.name [2]
  Gene.name    Gene.info                                       Gene.info.complete                                             
  <chr>        <chr>                                           <chr>                                                          
1 fam162a      membrane                                        membrane,integral component of membrane                        
2 fam162a      integral component of membrane                  membrane,integral component of membrane                        
3 fam162a      membrane                                        membrane,integral component of membrane                        
4 fam162a      integral component of membrane                  membrane,integral component of membrane                        
5 LOC101885363 nucleic acid binding                            nucleic acid binding,RNA polymerase II regulatory region seque~
6 LOC101885363 RNA polymerase II regulatory region sequence-s~ nucleic acid binding,RNA polymerase II regulatory region seque~
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I think something like this might be what you're looking for...

I've made a minimal example dataset - `test_data` containing some genes & some annotations.

```
test_data=data.frame(gene_name=rep(c("gene1","gene2","gene3"),each=4),
    annotation=c("important","interesting","useful","cool","useless","unimportant","boring","dull","neutral","so-so","borderline","average"))
```

Let's say you have your list of the names of your genes of interest in a vector:

```
gene_name_list=c("gene1","gene2")
```

We can use this to get all the annotations for each one, separated by commas:

```
gene_annotations = sapply(gene_name_list,function(gene_name) paste( unique( test_data[test_data[,"gene_name"]==gene_name,"annotation"]), collapse="," ) )
gene_annotations
#                               gene1                               gene2 
# "important,interesting,useful,cool"   "useless,unimportant,boring,dull"
```